# How do the elements of a covariance matrix differ from individual covariances?

Tags: python, covariance

In particular, I get this when I use numpy:

```
>>> np.cov(np.transpose([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,7],[7,8,9],[4,3,2]]))
array([[ 5.3,  5.1,  5. ],
       [ 5.1,  5.7,  6.5],
       [ 5. ,  6.5,  8.5]])
```

But the covariance of `[2,3,5,8,3]` and `[2,3,5,8,3]` is `4.56`, not `5.7` .. What's going on? I mean obviously numpy's not wrong, but the online sources I've read say that the covariance matrix just contains the covariances of `Xi,Xj` from the original matrix, and it would seem this isn't the case. Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the difference - instead of taking the average, numpy's cov (and some other places' cov) takes the sum and divides by `n - 1` not by `n`. I don't know why it does this, so I won't mark mine as the answer if someone is willing to elaborate.

Comment: If you divide by $n$ you get a biased estimate of variance, if you divide by $n - 1$ you get an unbiased estimate of variance. You can calculate both with np.cov. See documentation docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html